# Remove reationship from many-to-many models in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I tried the following:

```
$one = OneModel::findOrFail($id);
$two = $one->two_model()->findOrFail($two_id);
$two->delete();
```

But that deletes the record from the database, how can I just remove the relationship without deleting from the table? And also not having to mess with the pivot table, because if that is needed, why am I even using a framework...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If I got you correctly, `detach()` is what you're looking for:

```
$one = OneModel::findOrFail($id);
$one->two_model()->detach($two_id);
```

This will delete only the relation with `one_model`'s table's `$id` and `two_model`'s table's `$two_id` in your pivot table.

[Click here for more details](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables).